# How to make `eval` to use specific path to resolve `include` in Julia?

Tags: julia

This expression `eval(Meta.parse("begin $(code)\nend"))` would eval Julia code with `include` resolved relative to the file `eval...` is defined in.

How to change it so that it would use another directory? Something like

```
eval(Meta.parse("begin $(code)\nend"), resolve_include_relative_to=somepath)
```

Or, if that's not possible - relative to current directory (like REPL)?

**UPDATE**

Possible solution - replacing relative paths with absolute

```
function fix_include(code::String, relative_path::String)::String
  code = replace(code, r"include\(\"\./(.*?)\"\)" => s"include(\"__relative_path__/\1\")")
  code = replace(code, r"__relative_path__" => relative_path)
  code
end

eval(Meta.parse("begin $(fix_include(code, relative_path))\nend")
```

**Use case:**

I'm evaluating snippets of string code, sometimes they contain `include` statement with relative paths and they resolved against wrong path. I want to explicitly specify tell it what path should be used for resolution. Or at the very least always use the current directory '.', not the directory where the file with the `eval(xxx)` line defined `./lib/runner.jl`.

Comment: Would wrapping `eval` in a `cd` like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59473644/2442087 work?

Comment: No, I don't control the code that will be evaluated.

Comment: @giordano Please check the question, I updated it with the possible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function should do the trick (`include` is relative to the path in task-local storage, as kinda indicated by the docstring):

```
function eval_at(code; path = "none", mod = Main)
    tls = task_local_storage()
    hassource = haskey(tls, :SOURCE_PATH)
    hassource && (path′ = tls[:SOURCE_PATH])
    # setting this is enough for `include` to be correct
    tls[:SOURCE_PATH] = path

    try
      # let's use the three-arg `include_string` here to make sure `@__FILE__`
      # etc resolve correctly
      return include_string(mod, code, path)
    finally
      hassource ?
        (tls[:SOURCE_PATH] = path′) :
        delete!(tls, :SOURCE_PATH)
    end
end
```

Example usage:

```
julia> pwd()
"/home/pfitzseb/Documents"

julia> isfile("test.jl")
false

julia> include("test.jl")
ERROR: could not open file /home/pfitzseb/Documents/test.jl

julia> eval_at("""include("test.jl")""", path = "/home/pfitzseb/foo.jl")
Main.LogT

julia> eval_at("""@__FILE__""", path = "/home/pfitzseb/foo.jl")
"/home/pfitzseb/foo.jl"
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! One question - what the tick means in `path′`?

Comment: Oh, that's just to give it a different name from `path` (typed as `path\prime<tab>`). Could just as well be `oldpath` or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what exactly you want to do but for *"do something in a folder"* situations usually `cd() do ... end` syntax works great.

```
 code = quote
     cd("c:/temp") do
         println("do something in $(pwd())")
         #do something more
     end
 end
```

And now use it

```
julia> eval(code)
do something in c:\temp
```

Depending in your scenario you might consider using macros to manipulate code blocks that do something in a directory. Below is a simple example not offering more functionality than `cd ... do ... end` statement but of course it can be extended:

```
macro doinfolder(folder, what)
    isa(what, Expr) || error("what needs to be some expression")
    quote
        cd($folder) do
            $what
            #other useful code injections can occur here...
        end
    end
end
```

And now use it

```
julia> @doinfolder "C:\\temp" pwd()
"C:\\temp"
```

Will also work with more complex code structures

```
julia> @doinfolder "C:\\temp" begin
       pwd()
       end
"C:\\temp"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to eval the code as a raw string, like Jupyter does. Sometimes that code contains `include` statements, and everything breaks. Because `eval(xxx)` line defined in `lib/runner.jl` and Julia tries to evaluate code relative to `lib/runner.jl` file. I want to be able to tell it to evaluate it like `eval(code, relative_to="./another_file.jl")`

Comment: I guess one option would be to parse the code string, and replace all the occurrences of `include` with absolute paths...

Comment: Please check the question, I updated it with the possible solution.

Comment: You can use command such as `cd("c:\\temp") do; eval(Meta.parse("pwd()")); end`

Comment: The problem is that `include` inside of `eval` ignores the current directory so even if you change it - `include` inside `eval` still does not work.

Comment: `cd("c:\\temp") do; eval(Meta.parse("include(joinpath(pwd(),\"some.jl\"))"));end`